# How do you combine multiple TUI forms to write more complex applications?

Tags: python, console-application, urwid, tui, npyscreen

I would like to write a program with a **T**ext-based **U**ser **I**nterface ([TUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface)) that consists of several forms.

[image: Presentation of the several forms.]

- The first form contains a "list". Each list element represents a button.
- If the respective button is pressed, another form should appear in which one can enter the data for the list entry.
- Then the first form is displayed again (with updated list entries).

Here is my attempt, which uses the library [npyscreen](https://npyscreen.readthedocs.io/introduction.html) but does not return to the first form. The code does also not contain the logic to change the list item.

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# coding:utf8

import npyscreen

# content
headers = ["column 1", "column 2", "column 3", "column 4"]
entries = [["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"],
           ["b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"],
           ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"],
           ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"], 
           ["e1", "e2", "e3", "e4"]]


# returns a string in which the segments are padded with spaces.
def format_entry(entry):
    return "{:10} | {:10} | {:10} | {:10}".format(entry[0], entry[1] , entry[2], entry[3])


class SecondForm(npyscreen.Form):
    def on_ok(self):
        self.parentApp.switchFormPrevious()

    # add the widgets of the second form
    def create(self):
        self.col1 = self.add(npyscreen.TitleText, name="column 1:")
        self.col2 = self.add(npyscreen.TitleText, name="column 2:")
        self.col3 = self.add(npyscreen.TitleText, name="column 3:")
        self.col4 = self.add(npyscreen.TitleText, name="column 4:")


class MainForm(npyscreen.Form):    
    def on_ok(self):
        self.parentApp.switchForm(None)

    def changeToSecondForm(self):
        self.parentApp.change_form("SECOND")

    # add the widgets of the main form
    def create(self):
        self.add(npyscreen.FixedText, value=format_entry(headers), editable=False, name="header")

        for i, entry in enumerate(entries):
            self.add(npyscreen.ButtonPress, when_pressed_function=self.changeToSecondForm, name=format_entry(entry))


class TestTUI(npyscreen.NPSAppManaged):
    def onStart(self):
        self.addForm("MAIN", MainForm)
        self.addForm("SECOND", SecondForm, name="Edit row")

    def onCleanExit(self):
        npyscreen.notify_wait("Goodbye!")

    def change_form(self, name):
        self.switchForm(name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tui = TestTUI()
    tui.run()
```

Comment: Hello! This is a very interesting question, thanks for asking! I know you've retagged it as npyscreen (I'm following the urwid tag), I'm going to give it a try to implementing this in urwid because I'm generally intested on it, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Hello, every approach is more than welcome! I also removed the limitation to a specific library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what follows is my take to this problem, which can be described as an implementation of a [master-detail user interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master%E2%80%93detail_interface) for the console.

This uses the [urwid library](http://urwid.org), building some [custom widgets](http://urwid.org/manual/widgets.html#custom-widgets) to achieve the described UI, which has two modes: master view (where the main widget is a pile of records) and the detail view (an overlayed dialog, with the master view behind).

There are many things that can be improved, including making it look prettier. :)

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Sample program demonstrating how to implement widgets for a master-detail UI
for a list of records using the urwid library (http://urwid.org)
"""

from __future__ import print_function, absolute_import, division
from functools import partial
import urwid


PALETTE = [
    ('bold', 'bold', ''),
    ('reveal focus', 'black', 'dark cyan', 'standout'),
]


def show_or_exit(key):
    if key in ('q', 'Q', 'esc'):
        raise urwid.ExitMainLoop()


HEADERS = ["Field 1", "Field 2", "Field 3", "Field 4"]
ENTRIES = [
    ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"],
    ["b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"],
    ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"],
    ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"],
    ["e1", "e2", "e3", "e4"],
    ["e1", "e2", "e3", "e4"],
    ["f1", "f2", "f3", "f4"],
    ["g1", "g2", "g3", "g4"],
    ["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4"],
]


class SelectableRow(urwid.WidgetWrap):
    def __init__(self, contents, on_select=None):
        self.on_select = on_select
        self.contents = contents
        self._columns = urwid.Columns([urwid.Text(c) for c in contents])
        self._focusable_columns = urwid.AttrMap(self._columns, '', 'reveal focus')
        super(SelectableRow, self).__init__(self._focusable_columns)

    def selectable(self):
        return True

    def update_contents(self, contents):
        # update the list record inplace...
        self.contents[:] = contents

        # ... and update the displayed items
        for t, (w, _) in zip(contents, self._columns.contents):
            w.set_text(t)

    def keypress(self, size, key):
        if self.on_select and key in ('enter',):
            self.on_select(self)
        return key

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s(contents=%r)' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.contents)


class CancelableEdit(urwid.Edit):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.on_cancel = kwargs.pop('on_cancel', None)
        super(CancelableEdit, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def keypress(self, size, key):
        if key == 'esc':
            self.on_cancel(self)
        else:
            return super(CancelableEdit, self).keypress(size, key)


def build_dialog(title, contents, background, on_save=None, on_cancel=None):
    buttons = urwid.Columns([
        urwid.Button('Save', on_press=on_save),
        urwid.Button('Cancel', on_press=on_cancel),
    ])
    pile = urwid.Pile(
        [urwid.Text(title), urwid.Divider('-')]
        + contents
        + [urwid.Divider(' '), buttons]
    )
    return urwid.Overlay(
        urwid.Filler(urwid.LineBox(pile)),
        urwid.Filler(background),
        'center',
        ('relative', 80),
        'middle',
        ('relative', 80),
    )


class App(object):
    def __init__(self, entries):
        self.entries = entries
        self.header = urwid.Text('Welcome to the Master Detail Urwid Sample!')
        self.footer = urwid.Text('Status: ready')

        contents = [
            SelectableRow(row, on_select=self.show_detail_view)
            for row in entries
        ]
        listbox = urwid.ListBox(urwid.SimpleFocusListWalker(contents))

        # TODO: cap to screen size
        size = len(entries)

        self.master_pile = urwid.Pile([
            self.header,
            urwid.Divider(u'─'),
            urwid.BoxAdapter(listbox, size),
            urwid.Divider(u'─'),
            self.footer,
        ])
        self.widget = urwid.Filler(self.master_pile, 'top')
        self.loop = urwid.MainLoop(self.widget, PALETTE, unhandled_input=show_or_exit)

    def show_detail_view(self, row):
        self._edits = [
            CancelableEdit('%s: ' % key, value, on_cancel=self.close_dialog)
            for key, value in zip(HEADERS, row.contents)
        ]
        self.loop.widget = build_dialog(
            title='Editing',
            contents=self._edits,
            background=self.master_pile,
            on_save=partial(self.save_and_close_dialog, row),
            on_cancel=self.close_dialog,
        )
        self.show_status('Detail: %r' % row)

    def save_and_close_dialog(self, row, btn):
        new_content = [e.edit_text for e in self._edits]

        row.update_contents(new_content)

        self.show_status('Updated')
        self.loop.widget = self.widget

    def close_dialog(self, btn):
        self.loop.widget = self.widget

    def show_status(self, mesg):
        self.footer.set_text(str(mesg))

    def start(self):
        self.loop.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App(ENTRIES)
    app.start()
```

The `App` class holds the state of the app, keeping track of the main widgets and contains methods that are called upon user actions like hitting the buttons save/cancel.

The records are updated inplace, in the method `update_contents` of the SelectableRow widget, which represents a record being displayed in the master list.

The `CancelableEdit` widget exists just to be able to react to <kbd>esc</kbd> from the dialog window.

Feel free to ask any further clarifying question, I tried to use decent names and keep the code more or less readable, but I know that there is also a lot going on here and I'm not sure what needs to be explained in detail.

This was a fun exercise, thanks for giving me the excuse to do it! =)

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Your answer is also very instructive regarding [user interface design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_interface_design).

Answer (score 2):

I found myself using Npyscreen and so I found your question. If you're still working on this application, here is your initial code, but returning to the main form this time:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# coding:utf8

import npyscreen

# content
headers = ["column 1", "column 2", "column 3", "column 4"]
entries = [["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"],
           ["b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"],
           ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"],
           ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"],
           ["e1", "e2", "e3", "e4"]]

# returns a string in which the segments are padded with spaces.
def format_entry(entry):
    return "{:10} | {:10} | {:10} | {:10}".format(entry[0], entry[1] , entry[2], entry[3])

class SecondForm(npyscreen.Form):
    def on_ok(self):
        self.parentApp.switchFormPrevious()
        # add the widgets of the second form
    def create(self):
        self.col1 = self.add(npyscreen.TitleText, name="column 1:")
        self.col2 = self.add(npyscreen.TitleText, name="column 2:")
        self.col3 = self.add(npyscreen.TitleText, name="column 3:")
        self.col4 = self.add(npyscreen.TitleText, name="column 4:")

    def afterEditing(self):
        self.parentApp.setNextForm("MAIN")

class MainForm(npyscreen.Form):
    def on_ok(self):
        self.parentApp.switchForm(None)

    def changeToSecondForm(self):
        self.parentApp.change_form("SECOND")

    # add the widgets of the main form
    def create(self):
        self.add(npyscreen.FixedText, value=format_entry(headers), editable=False, name="header")

        for i, entry in enumerate(entries):
            self.add(npyscreen.ButtonPress, when_pressed_function=self.changeToSecondForm, name=format_entry(entry))


class TestTUI(npyscreen.NPSAppManaged):
    def onStart(self):
        self.addForm("MAIN", MainForm)
        self.addForm("SECOND", SecondForm, name="Edit row")

    def onCleanExit(self):
        npyscreen.notify_wait("Goodbye!")

    def change_form(self, name):
        self.switchForm(name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tui = TestTUI()
    tui.run()
```